# How do you re-install only the magento default mysql database, tables and data?

Tags: magento2

I was working through a problem with mysql and eventually purged it and reinstalled it on the system. Now magento db and all related tables are gone. How can I re-install the original database and tables and records without re-installing everything and losing custom php/JS code changes?

I'm working with magento2 on Ubuntu 16.04